# Swagger and Springfox Changing the example response for different status codes

Tags: java, spring-boot, springfox

I have a specific DTO I'm using to return as an example for Swagger documentation. How can I change the example in case I have a success 201 code?

Example responses in swagger:

[image: Example responses in swagger]

I use the annotations "@ApiModelProperty" to describe my objects, but finding no way on how to change the example for different response codes. In my code, I don't want to show the Errors list, as it's an optional property and it will just be available when non 201 codes are going to be produced.

Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a couple of annotations as follows:

```java
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.ExampleObject;

@Operation(summary = "Your summary")
@ApiResponses(value = { 
  @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "Your description", 
    content = { @Content(mediaType = "application/json", 
      schema = @Schema(implementation = YourModel.class),
      examples = [@ExampleObject(value = "{\"timestamp\": 1581552186590, \"status\": 404, \"error\": \"Not Found\", \"message\": \"Error message\", \"requestId\": \"62bcf95d\"}")]) })})
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. This is how that's being done, although, the problem is I cannot set different values as examples for my class. For example, in 200 scenarios, my error list should be empty though, and not show there. I don't want to create yet another DTO just to exemplify for Swagger.

Comment: Sorry, I am not following you. If you don't have such DTOs how do you respond with different content?

Comment: The point is - it becomes massive if we need to create a different DTO for a each different response. For example, I want my API consumer to know that when the API fails, it will throw out an error list showing the details. The DTO though is the same, but the "errors" list is an optional parameter, meaning that it will be populated only when the 50x errors are going out. So I just want to give my consumer a different example of my DTO, one with errors filled up, and the other one without it (in case of 20x status codes). My question is if we have a way to expose that having a single DTO.

Comment: In that case you can add the example as a JSON string with `@ApiResponse` `examples` attribute as follows: `examples = [ExampleObject(value = "{\"timestamp\": 1581552186590, \"status\": 404, \"error\": \"Not Found\", \"message\": \"Error message\", \"requestId\": \"62bcf95d\"}")]`. I've added it to my answer for readability.

Comment: Thanks, that actually solved the issue!

Comment: Awesome! Then consider upvoting my answer and accept it as the correct answer so that others can benefit from it and easily understand which could be a possible solution for similar questions ;) Thanks!